# Why does my looping code stop working after around 9 cells/loops?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Code purpose: Record each edited cell's edit date in a note, then search for duplicates of that cell's value in other sheets (including the current sheet), then add sheet name and row location of duplicates (if any) to note.

Problem: Code works fine when editing individual cells or pasting a range of up to 8 or 9 cells, but anything larger and the code will stop at the date recording step of the 9th or 10th cell.

I thought it might be a problem with the code getting confused when one selects another cell after the macro starts, so I've ensured that nothing tries to grab an active cell.

I thought it might be because it's too resource intensive, and have tried to optimize the code (I know it's very clunky and inefficient, do let me know if you have any tips on how to optimize it).

I've tried fiddling with the numbers and searching for numbers like 9, 10, 15, to see if I've unwittingly placed a numbered limiter on the code.

```
function onEdit(e){
  var keyword1 = "未確定"
  var keyword2 = "確定用語集"

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var activeSheetName = activeSheet.getName();

  //check to see if this is a sheet we want the macro to be running on
  if ((activeSheet.getName().indexOf(keyword1)>-1 || activeSheet.getName().indexOf(keyword2)>-1) && e.range.columnStart >= 6 &&  e.range.rowStart >= 3 ){


    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //make list of searchable sheets (for dupe searching later)

    var allSheets = ss.getSheets();
    var confirmSheet = ss.getSheetByName(keyword2); 

    var allSheetsNameArray = allSheets.map(function(sheet){return [sheet.getName()];});
    var targetSheetArray = [confirmSheet.getName()];

    //build target sheet list
    for(var a = 0; a < allSheetsNameArray.length; a++){

      if(allSheetsNameArray[a][0].indexOf(keyword1) > -1){

        targetSheetArray.push(allSheetsNameArray[a][0])
      }
    };


    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    // Then start looking at each cell in the edited range
    var range = e.range;
    var numRows = range.getNumRows();
    var numCols = range.getNumColumns();

    for (var i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
      for (var j = 1; j <= numCols; j++) {

        //When looking, get the currently counted cell's coordinates and value
        var currentCell = range.getCell(i,j)
        var currentValue = currentCell.getValue();

        //Before starting, reset cell color
        //currentCell.setBackground(null)

        //if the cell is blank, DO NOTHING
        if (currentValue != ""){

          var message = currentCell.getNote()

          //Set a note on it with the contents being: a copy of the previous note (returns blank if none), the date formatted year/month/day/time, followed by a separator and the currently entered value.
          message += ( 
            Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+9","yy/MM/dd HH:mm") + " | " + 
            currentValue + 
            String.fromCharCode(10)
          );


//--------------------Problem area?-----------------------------         
          //check for duplicates

          //loop through every name in the list of sheet we want to search (list made at beginning of code)
          for (var b = 0; b <targetSheetArray.length; b++){ 

            //targetSheet is the sheet we will be looking for duplicates in, sourceSheet is the sheet we are on and contains the word we want to search
            var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(targetSheetArray[b]);
            var sourceSheet = activeSheet;
            var sourceCell = currentCell;

            //store all values in the target sheet into an array
            var values = targetSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
            var searchString = sourceCell.getValue();
            var column = sourceCell.getColumn();

            //loop through every item in the value array
            for(var k=0; k < values.length; k++) {

              //find out if the value we're searching equals a value in the array. Value must not be in the same position as our current source cell.
              if(values[k][column-1] == searchString && k+1 != sourceCell.getRow()) {

                //If we've found a duplicate we make a note of what sheet and what row it's on.
                message += ("└ 重複:"　+  targetSheetArray[b]+  (k+1) + "行目"+ String.fromCharCode(10));


              };
            };
          };

          sourceCell.setNote(message);
//--------------------------------------------------------------------              

        }

      }

    }
  }
};
```

The code should be able to process any number of cells/values that are pasted into the sheet.

UPDATE: I've cleaned up the code a little more, and after some experimentation I can see that the code will continue throughout the range if I remove the duplicate checking section. Perhaps that's where the problem lies?

Comment: Are you sure the code has not just timed out. Simple triggers time out after 30 seconds. Check execution log.

Comment: Thank you so much! I used an installable trigger and the problem's solved! You the man, Cooper!